# Display Component from an array of components

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I want to find component from a list of components(or list of names of components) by name without loading components. Eg:

```
const arr = [
  <ComponentA />,
  <ComponentB />
]

const selectedComponent = arr.find(component => component.name === 'ComponentA');
```

and then render this `selectedComponent` in a div.

```
<div>{selectedComponent}</div>
```

**Note: ** Each component has unique name.

Comment: Is your array actually populated with Vue components or…? Because your array format as it is in your question isn’t valid.

Comment: @Terry its just an example. But its an array of components.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a `dynamic component` instead it will load your select component name like this example

```html
<component :is="component_name"></component>
```

and inside your data add the variable

```js
data(){
  return {
   component_name: 'home'
 }
}
```

For more info check the docs [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html)